# Why doesn't JToolBar appear?

Tags: java, swing, oop, jtoolbar

I have a Java project which has a functional JMenu. I'm trying to add a toolbar to it but it doesn't appear. I do get something I can drag which creates a blank window if I click around just under the menu bar.

```
protected JToolBar createToolBar(){
    JToolBar t1;
    t1 = new JToolBar();

    JButton test;
    test = new JButton("text here");
    t1.add(test);

    return new JToolBar(); 
}
```

This code might also be relevant.

```
protected Container createContentPane(){
    // Create the content-pane
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);

    // Create the toolbar
    JToolBar jt = createToolBar();
    contentPane.add(jt, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);           

    return contentPane;
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Sounds like you  didn't add the content pane to anything....

Comment: *"This code might also be relevant."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The content page is added to the frame, the same place as the menu is added.

Comment: umm, where is the `menu` again ? I can't see it

Comment: @user2079483  nope, can't answer before looking at the complete SSCCE code!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return new JToolBar();
```

needs to be

```
return t1;
```